# How to determine if user input is an number using a boolean function in C

Tags: c, integer, character

I am trying to figure out how to determine if the user input is a number and not a letter/symbol (A,a,!,@,#,$,%) in C, using a boolean function. The code I am using (if statement) only works for lower case and capitals letters. Below is my code for the if statement that works. Below that I will include the boolean function I am (unsuccessfully) attempting. Am I missing something in my boolean function?

```
    if((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')){
    printf("Character '%c' does not represent a digit\n", ch);}


    _Bool isNumber(char ch) {
    printf("Character '%c' does not represent a digit\n", ch);
    return 0;}
```

Is it possible without a library function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard library already *has* such a beast:

```
#include <ctype.h>
:
if (! isdigit(ch)) {
    printf("'%c' is not a digit\n", ch);
}
```

If, for some bizarre reason<sup>(a)</sup> you cannot use the standard library function, simply roll your own:

```
bool isDigit(int ch) {              // Uppercase D to distinguish it.
    return ch >= '0' && ch <= '9';
}
```

You can also do it directly in the code rather than as a function:

```
if (ch <  '0' || ch >  '9') puts("Not a digit"); // or:
if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') puts("Is  a digit");
```

The digit characters in C are *guaranteed* by the standard to be contiguous, unlike all the other characters. That's why doing the same for alphas (like `ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'`) is a bad idea.

Keep in mind that's for a *single* character being a digit. That appears to be what you want. To check if a character *string* is a valid integer, it'll need to be more complex. Basically, every character will need to be a digit, and it may have an optional sign at the front. Something like this would be a good start:

```
bool isInt(char *sstr) {
    unsigned char *str = sstr;
    if (*str == '+' || *str == '-')
        ++str;
    if (! isdigit(*str++))          // or your own isDigit if desired.
        return false;
    while (*str != '\0')
        if (! isdigit(*str++))      // ditto.
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Though I suppose you may want to do it for educational purposes, so not necessarily *that* bizarre :-)

Comment: Thank you :) this works perfectly! Just out of curiosity, can this be done using a Boolean function without using another library function? I was told there is a "special" trick to accomplishing such a goal.Will mark as correct answer in 4 minutes.

Comment: @MarkusZ, yes it can. Have added the boolean function to show how.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay true to your original logic, `if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'))` will be true if `ch` is any digit and false for any other character.